# Center of each side of a polygon

Tags: javascript, geometry, coordinates, center, polygon

Hi I have a polygon with coordintes

```
[
    [-73.9280684530257, 40.8099975343718],
    [-73.9282820374729, 40.8100875554645],
    [-73.9280124002104, 40.8103130893677],
    [-73.927875543761, 40.8102554080229],
    [-73.9280684530257, 40.8099975343718]
]
```

How I can find out the center of each side of this polygon using javascript?

Comment: if I have a line from [1,1] to [5,5] then the midpoint of the line is [3,3]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take the center by taking the average of the positions.

```js
var polygon = [[-73.9280684530257, 40.8099975343718], [-73.9282820374729, 40.8100875554645], [-73.9280124002104, 40.8103130893677], [-73.927875543761, 40.8102554080229], [-73.9280684530257, 40.8099975343718]],
    centers = polygon.map(function (point, i, points) {
        var neighbour = points[(i + 1) % points.length];
        return point.map(function (value, j) {
            return (value + neighbour[j]) / 2;
        });
    });

console.log(centers);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: It would be great if you change the variable's names to something more meaningful. It will be easier for all of us to follow the code.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution can be of this form

```js
var vertexArray = [[-73.9280684530257, 40.8099975343718], [-73.9282820374729, 40.8100875554645], [-73.9280124002104, 40.8103130893677], [-73.927875543761, 40.8102554080229], [-73.9280684530257, 40.8099975343718]];

var centerArray = [];
for(i=0;i<vertexArray .length;i++){
   nextIndex = (i+1)%vertexArray.length;
   centerArray[i] = [] ;
   centerArray[i][0] = (vertexArray [i][0] + vertexArray[nextIndex][0])/2;
    centerArray[i][1] = (vertexArray[i][1] + vertexArray[nextIndex][1])/2

}
console.log(centerArray);
```